# Can you read from two different files using a for loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a little piece of code for some Toontown source so that people can create SOS cards much easier. I have pretty much gotten everything together, but then this snippet of code jumps out at me:

```
for npcId, npcName in TTLocalizer.NPCToonNames.items():
```

Would it be possible to add the `or` statement so it can read from another file? This is what I had in mind:

```
for npcId, npcName in TTLocalizer.NPCToonNames.items() or CustomNPCsList.CustomNPCToonNames.items():
```

Comment: What behavior would you expect? Read all the items from one, then all the items from the other?

Comment: Well, did it work when you tried it?

Comment: I think you may want zip

Comment: [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) zips together two (or more) lists (actually iterables) into one list of tuples, so `[a, b, c, d, e]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` would come to you as `[(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4), (e,5)]`.  Does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to read from both files, one after the other. If not, could you please give us a little more context and/or clarify your question and expected result?

The best way to do this depends on the return type of the `items()` method. If it returns lists you could just use

```
for npcId, npcName in TTLocalizer.NPCToonNames.items() + CustomNPCsList.CustomNPCToonNames.items():
```

to generate a list containing items from both files. If `items()` is a generator or any other iterable type you could the `chain` function from the itertools package, which basically concatenates two iterables:

```
import itertools
for npcId, npcName in itertools.chain(TTLocalizer.NPCToonNames.items(), CustomNPCsList.CustomNPCToonNames.items()):
```

A small example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for number in itertools.chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6]):
>>>     print(number)
1
2
3
4
5
6
```